# cocoa -- reinitialize an object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios, reset

Suppose I want to reset an object to its initial state.  It seems like the natural thing to do would be to run it through its init method -- but Apple guidelines are that I only want to do this once.

Creating a new object is not a satisfactory solution, because I need to preserve pointers to the object from elsewhere.

The object is part of a large class hierarchy.  I will probably want to be able to reset most anything in the hierarchy.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `reset` method. This method could then in turn be called by `init` and if it is in a hiearchy all classes should implement it and call `super reset`.